# Prevent consecutive "." in email address in iPhone application

Tags: objective-c, ios6, nspredicate, email-validation

Is there any way to prevent consecutive `"."` in email address using `NSPredicate`? I can check it other way that whether current and previous input is ".". But I already use `NSPredicate`. Thus, if I just have to include some condition in that only then I prefer this. 
My code :

```
NSString * email = self.emailTextField.text;
NSString *emailRegex = @"[A-Z0-9a-z._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}";
NSPredicate *emailValidation =[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF MATCHES %@", emailRegex];
BOOL isValidEmail = [emailValidation evaluateWithObject:email];
```

Thank you.

Comment: Note that valid email addresses may contain consecutive ".". Don't make your validator too strict.

Comment: @GregParker But I have checked that email giants such as yahoo, gmail, hotmail do not allow consecutive `"."`. Can you give a real example where email does contain or can contain consecutive `"."`. By the way, thanks showing me red light.:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try modifying the middle part of your expression to use `(?!\\.)` *negative lookahead* for matches of the dot `.` character, like this:

```
[A-Z0-9a-z._%+-]+@([A-Za-z0-9-]|\\.(?!\\.))+\\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}
```

The `\\.(?!\\.)` anywhere in an expression says "match a single dot only when the symbol that follows is *not* a dot". The symbol that follows does not get consumed in the process of checking the *lookahead*. If you want to prevent dots in the e-mail's initial part as well, modify the part before `@` in the same way as the middle part:

```
([A-Z0-9a-z_%+-]|\\.(?!\\.))+@([A-Za-z0-9-]|\\.(?!\\.))+\\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}
```

Comment: thank you for answering. Can you tell me what this exactly does?And I want to prevent not only in middle part, but anywhere in email address.

Comment: +1. I'm not able test this right now. But I assume this will work.